# My NSString is determined to equal null, infuriating

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, nsstring, initialization

This has been bugging me all night, It doesn't make any sense. This function returns whatever it's supposed to. EG, the issueName.

```
-(id)initWithIssue:(NSString *)string {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSString *thing = string;
        issueName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:thing];
        NSLog(@"The issue name = %@", issueName);
    }
    return self;
}
```

However if I try to access 'issueName' in the viewDidLoad: nothing, it's equal to null no matter what I do. I've tried cleaning, setting a custom setter, switching between a property or a Ivar... ect. What's so infuriating is that this string just disappears at this point in the programe.

What the hell is going on, this is infuriating.

**Edit**

This the the entire code that is relevant. And how I started off.

Dot h file:

```
@interface BFPaidAreaViewController : UITabBarController <BFNewsTableViewControllerDelegate> {
    NSString *issueName;    
}
-(id)initWithIssue:(NSString *)string;
```

Dot m file:

```
-(id)initWithIssue:(NSString *)string {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // PLPiper I had it that way before, because I was fiddling out of frustration
        issueName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];
        NSLog(@"This is Called, the issue name is equal to = %@", issueName);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"The issue = %@", issueName);
}
```

I'm calling the view controller like so:

```
BFPaidAreaViewController *pavc = [[BFPaidAreaViewController alloc]initWithIssue:@"test"];
```

This will log:

```
This is Called, the issue name is equal to = test
The issue = (null)
```

**New Edit**

Found the problem. It's a UITableViewController. Strange, when I change it's class to a UIViewController it works. Is this a bug or just normal behaviour? But more pressing, how to I get round this limitation?

(Just to explain what I've done UI wise, the UITabBarController is in a modal View. This works fine with a UIViewController.)

**God Awful Fix**

```
-(id)initWithIssue:(NSString *)string {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSString *thing = string;
        issueName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:thing];
        NSLog(@"The issue name = %@", issueName);
    }
    [self viewDidLoad];
    return self;
}
```

Makes me feel dirty. But it will have to do for now, I can continue. If anyone can think of a solution please tell. Sorry about my feistiness, it was incredibly frustrating listening to people say, 'what the hell is this?? what is issueName?? an ivar??' when it was really implicit in the question.

Comment: Does it matter? it's pretty pretty obvious that it's either an Ivar or a synthesised Property. I've tried both, and I get the same result.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to double check that -initWithIssue: is actually being called?

Comment: Why would I need one? read the question. The init method returns whatever it's supposed to. ie: it NSLogs. It's the Ivar/Property  the viewDidLoad it determined to equal null.

Comment: @RolloMontgomeryKonig-Brock why so stubborn? Catfish_Man is just trying to make sure that your initWithIssue method is being properly called.

Comment: Yes it does matter what issueName is and how it is accessed, set and retreived. When you don't know what you are doing then you may easily end up with an ivar issueName and _issueName and may well get confused. Please proved all related code of your .h and .m related to declaration, property declaration, synthesize and custom setter, if any.

Comment: Can you stop down voting me. It's really undeserved.

Comment: Hmmm. Not any of the usual suspects then, based on the edit... Oh, what about the "one instance from the xib and another instance from code" issue? That's a pretty common reason for mysteriously uninitialized variables.

Comment: Might it be it's a UITableViewController?

Comment: @Catfish_Man, yes it is.

Comment: @RolloMontgomeryKonig-Brock, Is this issue fixed?

Comment: Are you sure it's the same instance emitting the logs?

Comment: Yes I fixed it but it's really hackery. I don't allow the viewDidLoad to run until I tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, replace:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // Unneeded nil arguments
```

with:

```
self = [super init]; // Equivalent method, less processing involved.
```

Secondly, replace:

```
NSString *thing = string;
issueName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:thing];
```

with just:

```
_issueName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];
```

If `issueName` is a property (and you haven't `@sythesized` it to anything else) its representation should be `_issueName`.

The above fixes are more or less just make the code more succinct. The issue is probably with the code in `viewDidLoad:` (See below).

---

Now you can initialise your `Issue` object, and use the following code to display the issue name:

```
// Init:
Issue *myIssue = [[Issue alloc] initWithIssue:@"Example Issue"];
// Log:
NSLog(@"%@", myIssue.issueName);
```

And the log should show:

`Example Issue`

Comment: Bizarre, this doesn't work. I'm going to post, everything in my code. This is infuriating. I've never seen something so determined to stay like this.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

make the issueName a property, like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *issueName;
```

then use it like this,

```
-(id)initWithIssue:(NSString *)string {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"The string = %@", string);
        self.issueName = string;
        NSLog(@"The issue name = %@", issueName);
    }
    return self;
}
```

if you are using the automated synthetized property (i.e not declaring the @synthentize manually for the issueName), then your iVar will be called _issueName instead of issueName

what do you get from the above code ?

Comment: As I explained that's not the problem, the init method is perfectly able to receive the string. The viewDidLoad method however is unable to use it, it returns null. 

I've even tried setting it as a property where I create the object.

Comment: This approach definitely works and is an obvious fix. The error is to do with your memory management, which by the looks of your posted code, isn't going to be good. If this approach fails for you, then there must be a problem somewhere else in your code. How are you accessing the variable in your VDL?

Comment: @RolloMontgomeryKonig-Brock if you do not want any help then do not ask for it. Fact is that you did make a mistake that you are not yet aware of. And we are trying to help. So plase choose your words accordingly.

Comment: @HermannKlecker you saved me from choosing mine a bit less carefully.

Comment: @RolloMontgomeryKonig-Brock: What is your property/ivar declared as? Weak, strong?

Comment: @sudorm-rf He must be using an iVar rather than a property.

Comment: @max_ But ivars are `__strong` by default under ARC.

Comment: I've used Ivars and properties. I've tried setting it as nonatomic,retain and nonatomic,strong. No avail

Comment: @RolloMontgomeryKonig-Brock: Stop flailing: it's not going to get you anywhere. Slow down and think about the suggestions given so far.

Comment: Also, don't use setters in -init.

Comment: @ipmcc, I didn't as a serious attempt. It was just out of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I find this somewhat curious. You call `[super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`. This leads me to believe that this might be a subclass of `NSViewController`. If you init an `NSViewController` like this, barring some other, pretty non-standard stuff, `-viewDidLoad` probably won't get called because there's no NIB to be loaded (because you passed `nil` to super). But clearly you're setting a breakpoint in `-viewDidLoad` so it's getting called (on something). This makes me think that you have this class specified in a XIB somewhere as a File's Owner or as a NIB-loaded custom object. If that's the case, it leads me to believe that the instance you're init-ing and the instance on which `-viewDidLoad` is being called aren't the same instance.  You can confirm this for yourself by putting `NSLog(@"self: %p", self);` in each method and seeing whether they are the same or different.

If the instance that is getting a call to `-viewDidLoad` is NIB-loaded, then your init method won't be called. Instead it will use `-initWithCoder`

If you can elaborate on the situation here (i.e. how this is getting instantiated, are there any XIBs involved, etc), I will edit my answer to provide more help, but I don't think there's enough information here to be truly helpful.

I feel your frustration. Assuming standard behavior, any of the suggestions here should have worked. This only reinforces my suspicion that these are not the same instance (between `-initWithIssue` and `-viewDidLoad`.